# Error getting email address - grafana with keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, grafana

I'm trying to integrate Grafana with Keycloak but I'm receiving the following errors when I'm setup the "Scopes = openid profile email" on **grafana.ini** :

```
t=2021-11-03T05:51:22-0400 lvl=eror msg="**Error getting email address**" logger=oauth.generic_oauth url=http://192.168.101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo/emails error="{\"error\":\"RESTEASY003210: C**ould not find resource for full path: http://101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo/emails**\"}"
t=2021-11-03T05:51:22-0400 lvl=eror msg="login.OAuthLogin(get info from generic_oauth)" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Error getting email address: {\"error\":\"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://192.168.101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo/emails\"}"
```

Definitely, is not getting any email addreess when I'm trying to call the  **"http://192.168.101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo/emails" - Page not found.**

My grafana.ini config looks like below:

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
team_ids =
allowed_organizations =
name = Keycloak
scopes = openid profile email
client_id = grafana
client_secret = ba342011-3705-483c-8e04-7f95be561cd5
auth_url = http://192.168.101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_url = http://192.168.101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/token
api_url = http://192.168.101.221:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

Comment: Same issue over here. Which KC version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

Step 1. Create an user on keycloak , for example : grafana and set an password and also you can add you email address or whatever email address you want :

[keycloak user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpJPo.png)